# Замена массива подстрок

Tags: массивы, php

Есть строка, необходимо заменить массив подстрок на другой массив:

```
исходная строка: '12'
массив подстрок: ('1', '2')
заменить на: ('_x12_', '_x2_')
ожидаемый результат: '_x12__x2_'
```

Пробовал через preg_replace :

```
print_r(preg_replace(array('/1/', '/2/'), array('_x12_', '_x2_'), '12'));
```

но результат 1-ой замены заменяется вторым элементом массива, т.е. получается: `_x1_x2___x2_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я ошибался..

```
$str = '4122121133';
$replaceMap = array(
    '1' => '_x12_',
    '2' => '_x2_',
    '12' => '_x13_',
    '121' => '_x14_'
);
echo strtr($str, $replaceMap);// 4_x13__x2__x14__x12_33
```

Comment: Пример, когда это работает некорректно:  

    $str = '4122121133';
    $replaceMap = array(
        '1' => '_x12_',
        '2' => '_x2_',
     '12' => '_x13_',
     '121' => '_x14_'
    );
    
    echo replaceStrMap($str, $replaceMap);
    //Ожидается 4_x13__x2__x14__x12_33
    //Выведет 4_x12__x2__x2__x12__x2__x12__x12_33

Comment: Теперь тоже неправильно:  

    //4_x12_2_x2_1_x2_1_x12_33 - неправильно
    //4_x13__x2__x14__x12_33 - правильно

Comment: @shurik,

    $str = preg_replace(array('/121/', '/12/', '/2/', '/1/'), array('{A}', '{B}', '{C}', '{D}'),'12');
    print_r(preg_replace(array('/{A}/', '/{B}/', '/{C}/', '/{D}/'), array('_x14_', '_x13', '_x2', '_x12'), $str));

Comment: @shurik кол-во комментариев ограничено тут. Позже еще свою реализацию закину )

@uzumaxy не думайте что данные такие статичные.

Comment: Только по ходу ответа на вопрос Я узнал, что в Вашем задании данные могут динамично изменятся и что можно использовать не только рег. выражения. Думаю, эту информацию необходимо было указать сразу же при создании вопроса...

Comment: @uzumaxy если бы данные были не динамичными, то можно было сразу ответ в виде константы написать, без всяких вычислений. А на счет метода решений, просто не было ограничений методов решений, и счел этого достаточным.

Comment: @IVsevolod, Вы меня неправильно поняли. Имею ввиду тип структуры данных: динамичная, статичная. Данные со статичной структурой легко описываются шаблоном, в отличии от данных с динамичной структурой.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: @shurik Нормально ) спасибо, вот этого я и искал :)

Comment: Браво! Плюс за то, что разобрались до конца и, в конечном итоге, нашли стандартную функцию для реализации поставленной задачи! :)